# DNVM error: cannot find dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0.-rc1-final

Tags: asp.net5, dnvm

I'm having some issues with dnvm.
The error that is displaying is this:

```
D:\development\Disqorse>dnvm use 1.0.0.-rc1-final
Cannot find dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0.-rc1-final, do you need to run 'dnvm install
1.0.0.-rc1-final'?
At C:\Users\Jonathan Smith\.dnx\bin\dnvm.ps1:1667 char:9
+         throw "Cannot find $runtimeFullName, do you need to run '$Com ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Cannot find dnx....0.-rc1-final'?:St
   ring) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0.-rc1-final, do you ne
   ed to run 'dnvm install 1.0.0.-rc1-final'?

'C:\Users\Jonathan' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

But when I run the above commands and try suggestions from SO I still get the same issue. Also interesting is the fact that after I carry out ANY commands I get the text at the bottom complaining there is a non-recognized command. I susepect this is because there is a space in the folder name which represents the current user. I can't be sure whether this is the problem or not though.

Comment: Changed the tag. RC2 is out, http://dot.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check script execution permission level in your powershell window. I set it to remote signed using:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Also, you need to supply the runtime and architecture as well:

```
like dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r clr -arch x64
```

Comment: You need to supply the runtime and architecture as well: like  dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r clr -arch x64

Comment: This seemed to work thanks. Please edit answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of dnvm has a bug and does not work when user name contains spaces.

One of the proposed solutions is to self-update it using

```
dnvm update-self
```

And if that does not work, try using new command-line interface that replaces dnvm. You can read about it in more details here - https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/190 (bottom posts)